# How can I format gas price with eth-hooks?

Tags: ether, gas-price, bignumber

```
import { useGasPrice } from 'eth-hooks' //using version 2.3.16

const NETWORK = {
  name: "mainnet",
  color: "#ff8b9e",
  chainId: 1,
  rpcUrl: REACT_APP_INFURA_ID,
  blockExplorer: "https://etherscan.io/",
}

export default function SettingsTab() {
    const gasPriceLow = useGasPrice(NETWORK, "safeLow", 1500)
    const gasPriceAvg = useGasPrice(NETWORK, "average", 1500)
    const gasPriceFast = useGasPrice(NETWORK, "fast", 1500)
    const gasPriceInstant = useGasPrice(NETWORK, "fastest", 1500)

    return (
                <Text>
                {gasPriceLow} gwei // ex, returns value: 310000000000 gwei
                </Text>
                <Text>
                {gasPriceAvg} gwei // ex, returns value: 350000000000 gwei
                </Text>
                <Text>
                {gasPriceFast} gwei // ex, returns value: 380000000000 gwei
                </Text>
                <Text>
                {gasPriceInstant} gwei // ex, returns value: 450000000000 gwei
                </Text>
          )}
      )
    }
```

Can someone point me in right direction for formatting so gas price returns as ex: 35 gwei? Thanks

Comment: can't you not just use the BigNumber and divide the result and convert from Gwei to Wei? or use etherjs https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/display-logic/#utils-parseUnits

Comment: doesnt seem to allow it.

Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)

Comment: got it to work by declaring new const gpl = Number(gasPriceLow) / 1e9

Comment: still learning here, realized i had to make it a variable and not const for it to get updates. Thank you for parseUints docs it lead me in right direction

Comment: take care ethereum numbers and values are too big that javascript cannot handle them. you should not just convert them to normal numbers like Number(bigNumber) you could loss data. and if you want to do mathematic  operation on them then you need to use the big number libraries

Comment: Thanks you. So i've converted them all using BigNumber but i have another issue, react-app no longer displays my app. no errors are thrown. Just global background is there and no app.